# Shortcut to particular document in Google Docs app?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-drive

Is there a way to make a shortcut to one particular document? I frequently need one particular document from a secondary account, so it's always a pain to come out of current document, change accounts and load the required document. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered sharing the document with the other account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround - use Google Docs via a browser, and bookmark that page.

Comment: It's easy to add bookmarks to the home screen, too.

Answer (score 0):

These days you can add a widget that directly links to a Google Doc. It seems like it doesn't work on all devices (or perhaps all home screens?) though, as on my girlfriend's phone the widget doesn't appear even though Google Drive (the app that allegedly provides the widget) is installed.