# Android Phone's Homescreen Shortcut to File on OneDrive

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, onedrive

I would like to put a shortcut on my Android phone's homescreen to a Word document file on OneDrive. When I touch the shortcut, the Microsoft Word app should open and allow for editing the file. If I save in Word, then the document should be uploaded to OneDrive online storage.

The OneDrive app allows me to put a shortcut (widget) to a folder but not a file. ES File Explorer allows me to put a shortcut to a file stored locally on the phone but not on a file stored on OneDrive.

I figure I need to download an app. Which app will work?

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30204/how-can-i-add-a-shortcut-to-a-particular-google-drive-document-to-my-android-hom) is similar except it is for Google Drive.

Comment: I'm coming from Windows world. In WP8 we could do it. With Windows 10 mobile we can pin only OneDrive folders but better than nothing. And now I think it's time to move to Android but this is a huge regression. Bad user experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add a shortcut to your desired document on the Android Home Screen. To do this however, you have to have the Microsoft Office Apps, like Word and Excell installed. Then open Word and locate your document either locally or in One Drive. Click the three dots next to the document and select add to Home Screen.

Comment: And what if it's not a Microsoft Office document?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Add a widget and select the folder you want, then Pin it.

**Source:** [10 Tricks to Make Yourself a OneDrive Master](https://gizmodo.com/10-tricks-to-make-yourself-a-onedrive-master-1683618001)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an all-purpose [Shortcut Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rk.android.app.shortcutmaker) app.

After installing the app, go to Widgets by long-tapping the home screen and click on shortcut maker. Then add the required file from Onedrive.

Comment: Please disclose, in full, any affiliation you have with this app.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Microsoft Edge browser then you get good integration with Office apps.

1. Get the url for the document by sharing it with some app or other.
2. Open the url in Edge.
3. Click the 'add to device' button.